JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll doesn't work after installation on Test PC
I am using JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll to connect to MS access db in windows From c# application. it works fine in development PC, when I make msi installer file with Wix toolset and install it on the Test PC, it gives me this error

Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type
'JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory'. Make sure that the
ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

and this is the wix toolset config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="CableJETSetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="CableJETSetup" UpgradeCode="e0f5d6cf-1f80-4f0a-a7b6-4fee17720d38">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="CableJETSetup" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="CableJETSetup" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

 <Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <!-- Component to install the application executable -->
  <Component Id="CableJETAPP" Guid="240f43a5-160d-48ab-92aa-06e08e463283">
    <File Id="CableJET" Name="CableJET.exe" Source="D:\PersonalProject\Cable\CableJET\CableJET\bin\Debug\CableJET.exe" />
  </Component>

  <!-- Component to install the database -->
  <Component Id="CableJETDatabaseComponent" Guid="b1f8d4b3-963e-48f7-b1d1-9b88d7a3e5b5">
    <File Id="CableJETDatabase" Name="Cable.accdb" Source="D:\PersonalProject\Cable\CableJET\CableJET\bin\Debug\CableDB\Cable.accdb" />
  </Component>
    
    <!-- Component to install the EntityFramework.dll -->
  <Component Id="EntityFrameworkDllComponent" Guid="554768d5-fd79-4799-81e7-bda9de82f2e5">
    <File Id="EntityFrameworkDALDll" Name="EntityFramework.dll" Source="D:\PersonalProject\Cable\CableJET\CableJET\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.dll" />
  </Component>
        
   <!-- Component to install the JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll -->
  <Component Id="JetEntityFrameworkProviderDllComponent" Guid="c522496e-0dd3-422c-afb9-1b2c51034bfb">
    <File Id="JetEntityFrameworkProviderDll" Name="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll" Source="D:\PersonalProject\Cable\CableJET\CableJET\bin\Debug\JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll"/>
  <Component Id="Log4netDllComponent" Guid="78a31bcf-a676-4fa5-816c-22fa41ab0f7d">
        <File Id="log4netDll" Name="log4net.dll" Source="D:\PersonalProject\Cable\CableJET\CableJET\bin\Debug\log4net.dll" />
    </Component>
  </Component>

</ComponentGroup>

and this is App.config
<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="logfile.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\CableJETSetup\Cable.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
</startup>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
    <provider invariantName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderServices, JetEntityFrameworkProvider"  />

    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
 </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
        <add invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider"
             name="Jet Entity Framework Provider"
             description="Jet Entity Framework Provider"
             type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory, JetEntityFrameworkProvider, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=756cf6beb8fe7b41" />

 </DbProviderFactories>
 </system.data>
 </configuration>

